# Upload to YouTube directly from stdin via Data API?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

As the title says, I want to pipe the output of a commandline encoder (that's recording a livestream) directly to YouTube via stdin.
Does the YouTube Data API have this functionality or is there some other little trick in order to accomplish this?

Comment: I don't see any support for streaming on the youtube streaming API, besides setting up information or retrieving information of current streams. Anyway, if you want to autostream you could look in to faking a a camera or whatever device that pushes the stream in. Streams are constant so you only have to configure the stream once.

Comment: Thanks. I created an issue (7956) asking for support in the next Data API patch.
The fake camera would probably work somehow but I'm using Google Drive now which is actually even better for my situation because it does not re-encode and supports upload via stdin.

Comment: That is interesting. Where do you play the video once you start uploading to drive ?

Comment: Google drive offers the YouTube player for video playback.
But because it won't re-encode after uploading, you'll have to do a few a tricks depending on what videoformat you are uploading (e.g. renaming .ts files to .mp4).
Alternatively, you download the video to your PC first.
Also, you can select videos from your Google drive when chosing to upload a video in YouTube and I guess you could do this via YouTube Data API, so that would be a solution to my original problem.